# Best approach for masking and predicting rasters (stratified model): maximise performance

Tags: r, performance, raster, mask, predict

This is a question on performance: The code below works well with the dummy data in the example, but scaling the problem to bigger data became very slow. I'm wondering if there is a better approach to do the same things.

**The problem**

I want to spatially predict a dependent variable *y* (forest growing stock volume in my real case study) based on a predictor *x* (forest age in my case study). I also have a forest types map (18 forest types) and I've built a  regression model (SVM with radial kernel) for each forest type. For each forest type, I want to predict *y* based on *x*.
I have annual data for the predictor *x* (forest age), so these operations must be done for every year
(6 years in the example).

**Scalability**

My problem is the computational time. My real rasters are quite big, and the analysis has to be repeated for 15 years. Below an example of my real rasters

```
#forest types map (this is a spatRast object created with terra::separate)
Class: RasterStack 
dimensions : 52175, 43480, 2268569000, 18  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 23, 23  (x, y)
extent     : 313260, 1313300, 4020285, 5220310  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
names      : X224, X324, X3111, X3112, X3113, X3114, X3115, X3116, X3117, X3121, X3122, X3123, X3124, X3125, X3131, ... 
min values :    1,    1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1, ... 
max values :    1,    1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1, ...


#example of one predictor (this is a RasterLayer object, read in R with raster::raster)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 52175, 43480, 2268569000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 23, 23  (x, y)
extent     : 313260, 1313300, 4020285, 5220310  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : E:/Elia_backup/FOR-EST/prova/disturbi_anni/2020.tif 
names      : X2020 
values     : 1, 35  (min, max)
```

Here is my current approach (adapted to the example data created ad hoc):

Create example data

```
library(raster)
library(terra)
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)
library(snowfall)

# generate data --------------------------------------------------------

set.seed(5)
#stack of predictor for 6 consecutive years
r1 <-r2 <- r3 <- r4 <- r5 <- r6 <-  m <- raster()
r1[] <-sample(1:16,ncell(r1),replace = T) 
r2[] <- sample(1:20,ncell(r1),replace = T)
r3[] <-sample(1:24,ncell(r1),replace = T)
r4[] <-sample(1:28,ncell(r1),replace = T)
r5[] <-sample(1:32,ncell(r1),replace = T)
r6[] <- sample(1:35,ncell(r1),replace = T)
#this stack contain the predictor for each year of the analysis
year_cut <- stack(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6)

#generate the raster mask (simulate land uses)
m[] <- rep(1:10,each=ncell(r1)/10)
#plot
plot(m)
#transform the land uses map in RasterStack with one layer for each land use
m <- separate(rast(m),other=NA)
m <- stack(m)
#rename layers
names(m) <- paste0("type",gsub("X","",names(m)))

#generate data frame of field observation
a <- sample(1:35,500,replace = T) 
g <- sample(seq(10,100,10),500,replace = T)
v <- ((a*runif(500)*g)^2+runif(500))/10000
s <- sample(names(m),500,replace = T)
#predictive models will be built form this data frame
df <- data.frame(a,v,s)
#plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=a,y=v,col=s))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~s,scales = "free")
```

Below I fit one model for each forest type

```
# models ------------------------------------------------------------------

#function for model fitting based on the land uses
mod_fit <- function(s){
  sample <- df[df$s==s,]
  fit <- train(v~a,data=sample,method="svmRadial",tuneLength=5)
}
#fit one model for each land use
models <- lapply(names(m),mod_fit)
#rename the list of models to match the name of the land use
names(models) <- names(m)
```

And finally, mask predictor in turn with the forest types and predict *y* (forest growing stock volume)  with the correspondent model. In this piece of code, I iterate the operations for every year (that is, for every raster predictors; in my example, for every layer of `year_cut`)

```
# mask and predict --------------------------------------------------------

#function for mask and predict
mypred <- function(x){
  #land use
  type <- names(x)
  #mask the predictor (cut, defined below) with the land use in "type"
  masked <- raster::mask(cut,x)
  #rename for predict
  names(masked) <- "a"
  #predict v~a based on the masked predictor, with the right model
  predicted <- raster::predict(masked,model=models[[which(names(models)==type)]],overwite=T)
}


# loop across "years_cut" ---------------------------------------------------

#here I store my results
tot <- as.list(1:nlayers(year_cut))


for (i in 1:nlayers(year_cut)) {
  #read the predictor for the current year
  cut <- year_cut[[i]]
  #unstack the land use mask
  l.list <- unstack(m)
  names(l.list) <- names(m)
  #set a parallel cluster with as many core as layer in the land use mask
  sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus =nlayers(m))
  # Load the required packages inside the cluster
  sfLibrary(raster)
  #export all variable in all the cluster
  sfExportAll()
  # Run parallelized function and stop cluster
  system.time(pred <- sfLapply(l.list, fun =mypred))
  sfStop()  
  #finally, summarize the prediction of each year in one single raster
  pred_stack <- stack(pred)
  #calc in parallel to make the sum of each layer in "pred_stack"
  beginCluster(10)
  tot[[i]] <-clusterR(pred_stack, calc, args = list(fun = sum, na.rm = T), m = 1)
  endCluster()
  
}#140 sec
```

This took 140 seconds on my PC, but on the real data, it took over 2 days to run.
I've tried to substitute the `raster` functions with the `terra` equivalent but, strangely, with `terra` I encounter memory issues, especially in the `mask` and `predict` part.

I know that the `predict` part is a typical `Map` problem. I'm wondering if I can substitute `sfLapply` with a parallel `Map` equivalent, like `future_map` or `parallelMap`. Or maybe a more efficient `sfLapply` call.  I'm open to all possibilities.

Comment: you could probably simplify your question a lot and attract more interest from the right audience. it seems to be "how to speed up predictions for a svmRadial model" and not at all about raster data (although I would of course be interested to know more about issues you encountered with terra::mask --- perhaps file an issue on github?).

Comment: surely `predict` is part of the bottleneck, but the problem here is bigger and closely related to the size of my data. the single prediction is not a problem, but the whole cycle
instead it is very long. I know that `predict` can be speeded up with `clusterR` for example, but is it advisable to use `beginCluster` within `sfLapply` or in general within a parallel version of the apply function? I just wanted to know if there are better ways to mask and predict large raster data in parallel. as soon as I have time I open an issue on Github for my problem with `terra`

Comment: My understanding or your question is that is about speeding up model::predict (that you can speed up and then supply to raster::predict) but yes there are other ways. A minimal example would be helpful.

Comment: My question is how to change the function `mypred` in the example to speed up the loop or how to change the loop itself to go faster. Since my function mask and applies a predictive model, it seemed appropriate to specify it in the title. However, the example in the question should be reproducible.

Comment: Those are two questions, I have tried to answer the first one, although not for your specific model

Answer (score 1):

Example data from `?terra::predict`

```
library(terra)
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
names(logo) <- c("red", "green", "blue")
p <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85, 66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31, 22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)
a <- matrix(c(22, 33, 64, 85, 92, 94, 59, 27, 30, 64, 60, 33, 31, 9, 99, 67, 15, 5, 4, 30, 8, 37, 42, 27, 19, 69, 60, 73, 3, 5, 21, 37, 52, 70, 74, 9, 13, 4, 17, 47), ncol=2)
xy <- rbind(cbind(1, p), cbind(0, a))
e <- extract(logo, xy[,2:3])
v <- data.frame(cbind(pa=xy[,1], e[,-1]))
```

build a model

```
library(randomForest)
model <- randomForest(formula=pa~., data=v)
```

Here are four ways to use the model to make a spatial prediction

Standard (not parallel)

```
r1 <- predict(logo, model)
```

Use build-in parallelization

```
r2 <- predict(logo, model, cores=2)
```

Write a parallel predict function

```
rfun <- function(mod, dat, ...) {
    ncls <- length(cls)
    nr <- nrow(dat)
    s <- split(dat, rep(1:ncls, each=ceiling(nr/ncls), length.out=nr))
    unlist(  parallel::clusterApply(cls, s, function(x, ...) predict(mod, x, ...))  )
}

library(parallel)
cls <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
parallel::clusterExport(cls, c("model", "rfun", "randomForest"))
r3 <- predict(logo, model, fun=rfun)
parallel::stopCluster(cls)
```

With the raster package you can also use `clusterR`

```
library(raster)
beginCluster(2)
b <- brick(logo)
r4 <- clusterR(b, predict, args = list(x=b, model=model))
endCluster()
```

There is no point in timing these approaches for this toy example. But `terra::predict` and `raster::predict` are not very costly, they just read and write chunks of data.

So to speed things up, I would focus on ways to make `model::predict` (replace with your model) go faster. One way is to write a parallel version and provide that as the `fun` argument to `raster::predict` or `terra::predict`. There can also be model specific things you can do. For example, if you can make a RandomForest model with 200 trees of the same quality as a model with 500 trees, then use the former to predict faster. You can test their performance by letting them make a million predictions or so; that is, independently of the raster data handling aspect.

If you have access to a HPC you can let each node do one of your forest classes.